# C - Creating IPC Channel using dup/fork/exec/wait

Tags: c, ipc

I am creating a simple shell that can handle a single pipe. I am having some issues getting my file descriptors to work here.

```
        int child_process_status;
        int fds[2];
        pid_t cpid1, cpid2;

        pipe( fds );

        if ( (cpid1 = fork()) == 0 ) {
            close(1); /* close normal stdout */
            dup( fds[1] ); /* make stdout same as fds[1] */
            close( fds[0] ); /* we don’t need this */

            fnd1 = find_fullpath( fullpath1, &p_cmd_array[0] );

            if ( fnd1 ) {
                if ( (cpid1 = fork()) == 0 ) {
                    execv( fullpath1, p_cmd_array[0].argv );
                }
            } else {
                printf("Command \"%s\" found.\n", p_cmd_array[0].name);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        if ( (cpid2 = fork()) == 0 ) {
            close(0); /* close normal stdin */
            dup( fds[0] ); /* make stdin same as fds[0] */
            close( fds[1] ); /* we don’t need this */

            fnd2 = find_fullpath( fullpath2, &p_cmd_array[1] );

            if ( fnd2 ) {
                if ( (cpid2 = fork()) == 0 ) {
                    execv( fullpath2, p_cmd_array[1].argv );
                }
            } else {
                printf("Command \"%s\" found.\n", p_cmd_array[1].name);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        close( fds[0] );
        close( fds[1] );

        waitpid( cpid1, &child_process_status, 0 );
        waitpid( cpid2, &child_process_status, 0 );
```

As you can see I have abstracted out all but the part where the fork/exec/wait happens. Everything else is working fine and is thus out of scope for this. What I am focusing on this the way I handle the file descriptors as that is where I think my problem is.

For example, I enter something like this: `ls -ln | wc -l` and I get `wc: stdin: read: Bad file descriptor` and it just hangs after that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the return value of `pipe`

Comment: Should have mentioned I tried that, it is `0`

Comment: are they valid before `dup`?

Comment: What do you mean by valid?

Comment: I would just try not closing them

Comment: You mean the close after dup and before the exec?

Comment: I mean the close before dup... and maybe the one after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71546/discussion-between-lampwins-and-grady-player).